# Can't Enable isc-dhcp-server on boot

Tags: debian, dhcp, isc-dhcpd, proxmox

I've installed DHCP Server on Proxmox/Debian and did the required configuration for it to be ready for use. However when I run the command

```
root@debian:~# systemctl enable isc-dhcp-server
isc-dhcp-server.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable isc-dhcp-server
```

I checked `/etc/systemd/system` I didn't find a file `isc-dhcp-server.service` there.

When running isc-dhcp-server via init.d it runs fine

```
root@debian:~# /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start
[ ok ] Starting isc-dhcp-server (via systemctl): isc-dhcp-server.service.
```

Verifying the status it's running without any issue.

```
root@debian:~# systemctl status isc-dhcp-server
● isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-02-09 07:59:09 EET; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
 Main PID: 24376 (dhcpd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 8.9M
      CPU: 13ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/isc-dhcp-server.service
           └─24376 /usr/sbin/dhcpd -q -d --no-pid -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf vmbr0

Feb 09 07:59:09 pvps systemd[1]: Started DHCP server.
Feb 09 07:59:09 pvps dhcpd[24376]: Wrote 0 deleted host decls to leases file.
Feb 09 07:59:09 pvps dhcpd[24376]: Wrote 0 new dynamic host decls to leases file.
Feb 09 07:59:09 pvps dhcpd[24376]: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
```

So Apparently everything is set well except I can't enable it on boot as shown at the top message. Any advice please, thank you!

Comment: Failed to enable unit: File dhcp.service: No such file or directory

Comment: Yes it's already declared that. I don't think this error is related to interface declaration however I can confirm to you it's declared already and dhcp is running using init command